# How to segment a matrix by neighbouring values?

Tags: python, matrix, grouping, image-segmentation

Suppose I have a matrix like this:

```
     m = [0, 1, 1, 0,
          1, 1, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 1]
```

And I need to get the coordinates of the same neighbouring values (but not diagonally):

---

### [image: like this]

So the result would be a list of lists of coordinates in the "matrix" list, starting with [0,0], like this:

```
r = [[[0,0]],   
     [[0,1], [0,2], [1,0], [1,1]],   
     [[0,3], [1,2], [1,3], [2,0], [2,1], [2,2]]   
     [[2,3]]]
```

There must be a way to do that, but I'm really stuck.

Comment: Just for clarification, is matrix a one dimensional array or 2 dimensional?

Comment: That is not fixed and can be changed however is more convenient.

Answer (score 5):

tl;dr: We take an array of zeros and ones and use [scipy.ndimage.label](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html) to convert it to an array of zeros and [1,2,3,...]. We then use `np.where` to find the coordinates of each element with value > 0. Elements that have the same value end up in the same list.

[image]

[scipy.ndimage.label](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html) interprets non-zero elements of a matrix as features and labels them. Each unique feature in the input gets assigned a unique label. Features are e.g. groups of adjacent elements (or pixels) with the same value.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import label

# make dummy data
arr = np.array([[0,1,1,0], [1,1,0,0], [0,0,0,1]])

#initialise list of features
r = []
```

Since OP wanted *all* features, that is groups of zero *and* non-zero pixels, we use `label` twice: First on the original array, and second on `1 - original array`. (For an array of zeros and ones, `1 - array` just flips the values).

Now, `label` returns a tuple, containing the labelled array (which we are interested in) and the number of features that it found in that array (which we could use, but when I coded this, I chose to ignore it. So, we are interested in the first element of the tuple returned by `label`, which we access with `[0]`:

```
a = label(arr)[0]
b = label(1-arr)[0]
```

Now we check which unique pixel values `label` has assigned. So we want the `set of a and b, repectively`. In order for `set()` to work, we need to linearise both arrays, which we do with `.ravel()`. We have to subtract `{0}` in both cases, because for both `a` and `b` we are interested in only the non-zero values.

So, having found the unique labels, we loop through these values, and use `np.where` to find where on the array a given value is located. `np.where` returns a tuple of arrays. The first element of this tuple are all the row-coordinates for which the condition was met, and the second element are the column-coordinates. 
So, we can use `zip(*` to unpack the two containers of length n to n containers of length 2. This means that we go from `list of all row-coords + list of all column-coords` to `list of all row-column-coordinate pairs` for which the condition is met. Finally in python 3, zip is a generator, which we can evaluate by calling `list()` on it. The resulting list is then appended to our list of coordinates, `r`.

```
for x in set(a.ravel())-{0}:
    r.append(list(zip(*np.where(a==x))))
for x in set(b.ravel())-{0}:
    r.append(list(zip(*np.where(b==x))))

print(r)

[[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1)],
 [(2, 3)],
 [(0, 0)],
 [(0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]]
```

That said, we can speed up this code slightly by making use of the fact that `label` returns the number of features it assigned. This allows us to avoid the `set` command, which can take time on large arrays:

```
a, num_a = label(arr)

for x in range(1, num_a+1): # range from 1 to the highest label
    r.append(list(zip(*np.where(a==x))))
```

Comment: Can you explain how this code works? It's so short!

Answer (score 4):

A solution with only standard libraries:

```
from pprint import pprint

m = [0, 1, 1, 0,
     1, 1, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 1]

def is_neighbour(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return (x1 in (x2-1, x2+1) and y1 == y2) or \
           (x1 == x2 and y1 in (y2+1, y2-1))

def is_value_touching_group(val, groups, x, y):
    for d in groups:
        if d['color'] == val and any(is_neighbour(x, y, *cell) for cell in d['cells']):
            return d

def check(m, w, h):
    groups = []

    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            val = m[i*w + j]
            touching_group = is_value_touching_group(val, groups, i, j)
            if touching_group:
                touching_group['cells'].append( (i, j) )
            else:
                groups.append({'color':val, 'cells':[(i, j)]})

    final_groups = []
    while groups:
        current_group = groups.pop()
        for c in current_group['cells']:
            touching_group = is_value_touching_group(current_group['color'], groups, *c)
            if touching_group:
                touching_group['cells'].extend(current_group['cells'])
                break
        else:
            final_groups.append(current_group['cells'])

    return final_groups

pprint( check(m, 4, 3) )
```

Prints:

```
[[(2, 3)],
 [(0, 3), (1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)],
 [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 0)],
 [(0, 0)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Returns as a list of groups under value key.

```py
import numpy as np
import math


def get_keys(old_dict):
    new_dict = {}
    for key, value in old_dict.items():
        if value not in new_dict.keys():
            new_dict[value] = []
            new_dict[value].append(key)
        else:
            new_dict[value].append(key)
    return new_dict

def is_neighbor(a,b):
    if a==b:
        return True
    else:
        distance = abs(a[0]-b[0]), abs(a[1]-b[1])
        return distance == (0,1) or distance == (1,0)

def collate(arr):
    arr2 = arr.copy()
    ret = []
    for a in arr:
        for i, b in enumerate(arr2):
            if set(a).intersection(set(b)):
                a = list(set(a+b))
        ret.append(a)
    for clist in ret:
        clist.sort()

    return [list(y) for y in set([tuple(x) for x in ret])]


def get_groups(d):
    for k,v in d.items():
        ret = []
        for point in v:
            matches = [a for a in v if is_neighbor(point, a)]
            ret.append(matches)
        d[k] = collate(ret)

    return d


a = np.array([[0,1,1,0],
              [1,1,0,0],
              [0,0,1,1]])

d = dict(np.ndenumerate(a))
d = get_keys(d)
d = get_groups(d)

print(d)
```

Result:

```
{
  0: [[(0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3)], [(0, 0)], [(2, 0), (2, 1)]], 
  1: [[(2, 2), (2, 3)], [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1)]]
}
```